# PHP Mysql Dropdown List Issue - It doesn't Update

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue regarding my project and i would like ur help to find a solution. I have a table in my database called albums which has 8 columns and those are id, album_name, image, artist, company, genre, price, category. I have create a backend for my project in order to update the website. I can update all of my columns beside the category column because it is a  list which has a 3 dropdown items which are the categories i have for my project and those are "new releases, popular albums, special offers. In my index.php i have show only 4 albums for the New Releases category, 4 albums for the Popular Albums category, 4 albums for the Special Offers category .The code in my index.php is this:

```
            <tr>
            <td width='120'>Category:</td>
            <td>
                <select name = 'categories'>
                    <option value = 'releases'>New Releases</option>
                    <option value = 'popular'>Popular Songs</option>
                    <option value = 'offers'>Special Offers</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

My backend code is this:

```
<?php
include('../../includes/database/db.php');


$id = $_GET['id'];
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$img = $_POST['image'];
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$category = $_POST['category'];

    if ($album_name!='' && $artist!='' && $company!='' && genre!='' && $price!='' && $category!='') {
    $sql = mysqli_query($dbconn, "UPDATE albums SET album_name = '".$album_name."',image = '".$img."',artist = '".$artist."',company = '".$company."',genre = '".$genre."',price = '".$price."',category = '".$category."' WHERE id='$id'");
    echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php?page=albums&action=list">'; 
}else{
    echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../index.php?page=albums&action=edit&msg=empty&id='.$id.'">';    
}

?>
```

What i would like is to update the category column for example if one album is in category New Releases, i would like to use the dropdown to put it in another category for example Special offers. I am trying to achieve this but it does not update. All the other columns in my table works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Might the empty 'id' field in your category option have anything to do with it?

Comment: no i have tried removing it but no luck

Comment: I can't find an opening `<?php` in your index.php? No `value` attribute in the options of your select? Your code is not complete!

Comment: The <?php is above that part and the closing ?> is below it. I just paste the code that i needed help. I have updated my code. Please have a look now and guide me how to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code is not properly constructed.

```
<select>
...
</select>
```

This field must contain a name attribute.

```
<select name="category">
...
</select>
```

You can then refer to it in your PHP code after being posted

```
echo $_POST['category'];
```

Comment: Ok  i have fixed the code can u explain me step by step how to proceed? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean step-by-step. Does the above not solve your problem?